# PrimeNG doesn't support RTL for table component

Tags: angular, primeng

I have used p-table in angular to display data and used scrollbar If it has scrollbars at page in English load, then it works fine, but has issues when we have a scrollbar at page in Arabic.

in english language:
[image-page-translate-to-english](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xseVX.png)

Here, I am adding rows to the table dynamically which creates scrollbar at runtime and at that time the header becomes misaligned.
So it only has scrollbar on body.

in arabic language:
[image-page-translate-to-arabic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f49TF.png)
`

```
.p-datatable table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}
```

`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have modified my issue for more understanding